# Formview alternative?

Tags: asp.net, formview

I'm looking to create a form that will always be in edit mode but I will need to bind to several tables. I want to display this as a cohesive page. I want to use databinding if possible and write as little code.

What are my options? Basically the FormView looked like a candidate but I don't want the edit buttons. I'll have 3 or 4 tables displayed on one page and I want a single button to submit it.

I know I could create a form and populate it manually but that seems like I may be doing more work then required.

Answer (score 2):

FormView is the right way to go. It is very customizable and you can change the layout by using custom templates. It also allows hiding the edit buttons you are talking about. Put some time learning that control and you will get what you want!

Answer (score 2):

Stay with the FormView; just set the `DefaultMode="Edit"`